# Android - AppCompat does not support the current theme features Error

Tags: android, themes, android-appcompat, android-styles, illegalargumentexception

My app was working fine until I deleted few layout files and activities. Since then its showing this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.skaprer.jope/com.skaprer.jope.Controllers.LoaderActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: AppCompat does not support the current theme features: { windowActionBar: false, windowActionBarOverlay: false, android:windowIsFloating: false, windowActionModeOverlay: false, windowNoTitle: false }
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                             Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: AppCompat does not support the current theme features: { windowActionBar: false, windowActionBarOverlay: false, android:windowIsFloating: false, windowActionModeOverlay: false, windowNoTitle: false }
                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:422)
                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:279)
                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:253)
                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109)
                                                                at com.skaprer.jope.Controllers.LoaderActivity.onCreate(LoaderActivity.java:39)
                                                                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251)
                                                                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

My LoaderActivity file where error occurs :

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    TwitterAuthConfig authConfig = new TwitterAuthConfig(TWITTER_KEY, TWITTER_SECRET);
    Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics(), new TwitterCore(authConfig), new Digits());
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_loader);
}
```

Theme files:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary_color</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark_color</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent_color</item>
</style>
```

v21 :

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary_color</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark_color</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent_color</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">#212121</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
</style>
```

Ever since the change, the app fails to start. I tried changing the intent filter to start different activities to check if the error is particular for the activity but with every activity i tried, the error remains. What should I do?

Comment: Can you also post manifest ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was an error because of the recent Android Studio 2.0 update, the IDE rebuilds the app for only the changed parts rather than rebuilding the whole thing. So I just clean and rebuild it, uninstalled the app from device and then run it. It worked.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
<item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
```

Answer (score 1):

**JUST performing a 'clean' task** has been solving my issuse. Seems once again to be one of these wierd Android Studio bugs.

Answer (score 0):

What version of AppCompat your are using?

It may be due to that AppCompat is now more strict on what it expect in theme window flags.

Try to add the next flag into your theme file:
`<item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>`

Comment: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1

Comment: I added windowNoTitle, still shows the same error, in the error it says  windowNoTitle: false as the current theme features

Comment: Which theme do you use for you activity? It would be better if you will also post your manifest. Have your added windowNoTitle to both theme files?

Comment: <application
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

Comment: Do you have any other themes? Try to rename your theme, apparently it may be also a problem. And also ensure that you are not setting any theme for activity in manifest or in code.